# 2D matrix to sql table

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, powershell

I have a csv file that I would like to transfer in a sql table. But the format of the file is:

> Date | id1 | id2
>
> 1/1 | 1.2 | 1.3
>
> 1/2 | 1.34 | 1.25

The way I want to store this in the table is:

> 1/1 | id1 | 1.2
>
> 1/1 | id2 | 1.3
>
> 1/2 | id1 | 1.34
>
> 1/2 | id2 | 1.25

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Is the data source a CSV or have you already imported into a table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you already imported the CSV into a temporary table with the same format as the CSV:

```
INSERT INTO new_table
SELECT date, 'id1' AS id_name, id1 AS id
FROM temp
UNION ALL
SELECT date, 'id2' AS id_name, id2 AS id
FROM temp
ORDER BY date, id_name
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e1ce2/1/1

Answer (score 0):

If open to a TVF, the following will convert virtually any Table, View or Query into an EAV structure.

**Notice** that we don't have to define any fields.  The only convention is that the FIRST column is the Entity

**Example**

```
-- Entire Table
Select * 
 From [dbo].[tvf-EAV]((Select * from YourTable for XML RAW) )


-- Or Row by Row via A CROSS APPLY
Select B.*
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-EAV]((Select A.* for XML RAW) ) B
```

**Both Return**

```
Entity  Attribute   Value
1/1     id1         1.20
1/1     id2         1.30
1/2     id1         1.34
1/2     id2         1.25
```

**The UDF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-EAV](@XML xml)
Returns Table 
As
Return (
    with cteKey(k) as (
         Select Top 1 xA.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') 
          From  @XML.nodes('/row')       A(xR) 
          Cross Apply A.xR.nodes('./@*') B(xA)
    )    
    Select Entity    = xR.value('@*[1]'        ,'varchar(100)')
          ,Attribute = xA.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
          ,Value     = xA.value('.'            ,'varchar(max)') 
     From  @XML.nodes('/row') A(xR)
     Cross Apply A.xR.nodes('./@*') B(xA)
     Where xA.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') Not In (Select k From cteKey)
)
-- Notes:  First Field in Query will be the Entity
-- Select * From [dbo].[tvf-EAV]((Select MyEntity=GetUTCDate(),* From sys.dm_os_sys_info for XML RAW))
```